# Filter Knowledge Articles search results by Brand (WHERE Brand = ...)

Tags: apex, query, knowledge

I'm making a **custom** Knowledge Search (it needs to be custom), and the basic query to search articles is `'SELECT Id, Title, Summary FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Title LIKE \'%' + input + '%\''`. This is in an Apex class that looks something like this:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Knowledge__kav> KnowledgeArticles(String input, String cat, String brand) {
    List<Knowledge__kav> knowledgeArticlesList = new List<Knowledge__kav>();
    
    // Searching in Knowledge Subject
    if (input != '' && input != null) {
        String queryBase = 'SELECT Id, Title, Summary FROM Knowledge__kav';
        String queryWhere = 'WHERE Title LIKE \'%' + input + '%\'';
        String queryLimit = 'LIMIT 10';
        
        if (cat != null && cat != '' && cat != 'All') {
            queryWhere += ' AND RecordType.Name = \'' + cat + '\'';
        }

        if (brand != null) {
            // queryWhere += ' AND ___ = \'' + brand + '\''; <<<===== ???
        }

        String knowledgeQuery = queryBase + ' ' + queryWhere + ' ' + queryLimit;

        knowledgeArticlesList = Database.query(knowledgeQuery);
    }
    return knowledgeArticlesList;
}
```

**Is there a brand field I can filter on?**

Looking at [this reference to `Knowledge__kav`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/sforce_api_objects_knowledge__kav.htm), I don't any sort of brand field...but I also don't see an Id field (but we're selecting Id and that works), and I suspect the data model for the knowledge articles is a bit complex ([see this post](https://www.sudipta-deb.in/2020/09/understand-salesforce-lightning.html)), so I don't know if it's as simple as finding a field in that Knowledge__kav reference page.

Comment: What is brand in this context? Is it some custom field you've created on the Knowledge object?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - oh you know what, I think it might be. Sorry I'm still pretty new at the Salesforce system, but if I go into Object Manager > Knowledge > Fields & Relationships, `Brand` does show up as a custom field - it's called `Brand__c` and is of type `Lookup(Account)`

Comment: Great, have you tried a query where you update it to `AND Brand__c = 'account id'`? If it doesn't work, feel free to [edit] your question with any relevant error message